# Checking to see if one or more ids is in a json string

Tags: sql, arrays, json, sql-server, t-sql

If I have the following rows in a table:

```
clientId    settings
1           {"franchises":[1,7,9,11,14,20,23,26,27,29,33,34,35,45,49,50,57,58,72,73]}
2           {"franchises":[1]}
3           {"franchises":[50]}
```

How would I query that to pull clientIds who have the franchises 1 or 50?

I tried doing

```
SELECT clientId FROM clientSettings WHERE JSON_VALUE(settings, '$.franchises') IN (1,50)
```

but that didn't work.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 3):

You can use json functions:

```
select distinct c.clientId
from clientSettings c
cross apply openjson(c.settings, '$.franchises') with (franchise integer '$')
where franchise in (1, 50);
```

Wrapping this in `exists` might perform better, since it avoids the need for aggregation:

```
select c.clientId
from clientSettings c
where exists (
    select 1
    from openjson(c.settings, '$.franchises') with (franchise integer '$')
    where franchise in (1, 50)
)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e33c0452b55f762319b9f40ec64ba500)** (I added a non-matching line to your dataset, with id `4`):

```
| clientId |
| -------: |
|        1 |
|        2 |
|        3 |
```

Comment: Is this tsql? I'm trying to run this on a sql 2019 instance and it's saying "Incorrect syntax near '$'"

Comment: @Brds: indeed this is tsql. It runs fine on SQL 2019 with your sample data, as you can see [in this DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fd35243f3bd82cb08db891842ed62ced).

Answer (score 0):

Another way that requires no sorting or aggregating.

```
DECLARE @clientSettings TABLE (ClientId INT IDENTITY, Settings VARCHAR(8000));

INSERT @clientSettings(settings)
VALUES
('{"franchises":[0,7,9,11,14,20,23,26,27,29,33,34,35,45,49,55,57,58,72,73,1,50]}'),
('{"franchises":[1]}'),
('{"franchises":[50]}');

SELECT c.clientId
FROM   @clientSettings c
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP (1) f.franchise
    FROM   OPENJSON(c.settings, '$.franchises') WITH (franchise INT '$') AS f
    WHERE  f.franchise IN (1, 50)
) AS x;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Please, try with below query using "CROSS APPLY OPENJSON"
>   ([SQL-FIDDL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d2a6c3cf5d6d85fbebfe303cf5ac9369)E):

```
SELECT c.clientId
FROM clientSettings c
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(c.settings, '$.franchises') with (franchise integer '$') as f
WHERE f.franchise in (1, 50)
GROUP BY c.clientId;
```